# unwanted line break after every record - spool oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I am getting line break after every record when I am trying to spool a csv using sqlplus. also I am putting value from every column inside double quotes "". can anyone please help me to understand why I am getting line break in csv file -

```
set serveroutput on size 1000000
set pagesize 0
set feedback off
set echo off
set verify off
set lines 32767
set trimspool on
SET TRIMSPOOL ON
set sqlblanklines off
set sqlterminator ';'
set space 0
SET TAB off
SET NEWPAGE NONE

spoo/test.csv



 SELECT    '"'
          || column1
          || '"'
          || ','
          || '"'
          || column2
          || '"' from table


Current outptut -
"r1c1","r1c2"

"r2c1","r2c2"

desired ouptup -
"r1c1","r1c2"
"r2c1","r2c2"
```

Comment: There is no parameter `lines`. You have to use `linesize` or short version `lin`. Default value of linesize is 80

Comment: @ArkadiuszŁukasiewicz: Have you tried `lines`. It works for me.

Comment: @Arkadiusz Łukasiewicz tried with linesize..still getting line break in output

Comment: @Pran: Are you expecting all the rows in a single line?

Comment: @Nitish: No I am not expecting all rows in a single line but do not want blank line after every record.

Comment: I asked because I'm getting your desired output with your code. No line breaks in between.

Comment: blank line is coming when data in column1 is splitted in 2 or more lines, then after the full record there is again a blank line

Comment: I'm getting your desired output, no breaks.  But, based on your last comment, you have example data that you have not shared.  Provide more information, such as your test data that is causing the undesired results.